# Libav/ X264 failed to compile with Hi422p profile and mp4 container support

Tags: libav, x264

My goal is to encode several videos from SD PAL captured in ProRes(HQ) 422 10bit through AJA Kona 3 to H264 with Hi422p profile in .mp4 container. I work on Mac OSX 9.

I try the last x264 10bit binaries from Videolan.
It as the ability to encode in the correct profile but is not compiled with GPAC nor l-smash.

So I struggle to understand (I’m  a novice) how to complete a clean install of libav/lsmash/x264 with all the good configuration option, in the correct order…. since at least a week.

My last try was to clean my `/usr/local` folder where there was too many dirty things after all, install libav and x264 using this link : http://www.xin.at/x264/x264-guide-macosx-en.htm.

But it seems that :

1. a lot of warning during the make process of libav

e.g first one :

```
**libavfilter/avfilter.c:292:20: warning: returning 'const AVFilter *' (aka 'const struct AVFilter *') from a function with result type 'AVFilter *' (aka 'struct AVFilter *') discards
      qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
            return f;**
```

2. at the end of the make install, it’s appear that nothing is installed neither in `usr/local/lib` or `usr/local/bin`.
3. So when i try to do a `./configure` on x264 I got a
   `« libav: no »`
   but as l-smash is installed I got
   `« mp4:lsmash »`

Comment: By "libav" are you referring to the FFmpeg libav* libraries, or the fork Libav that unfortunately chose the same name?

Comment: I refer to libav that you can source at libav.org.

Comment: But i succeed to compile everything now
MacBook-Pro-Regie:x264-10bit FDS$ x264 --version
x264 0.146.2538 121396c
built on Apr 16 2015, gcc: 4.9.2
x264 configuration: --bit-depth=10 --chroma-format=all
libx264 configuration: --bit-depth=10 --chroma-format=all
x264 license: GPL version 2 or later
MacBook-Pro-Regie:x264-10bit FDS$ x264 --help
x264 core:146 r2538 121396c

Comment: I'm not sure i can do an independant binairie with this now. For now i'm focus on encoding..

Comment: This question might get better answers at SuperUser

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about compilation, not use.